# Как правильно создать поле в абстрактном классе, которое должно быть в каждом подклассе?

Tags: java, классы

Есть абстрактный класс:

```
public abstract class SomeClass {
    String description;
    public String getDescription() { return description; }
}
```

Он имеет много подклассов, например:

```
public class SubClass extends SomeClass {
    public SubClass() {
        description = "description";
    }
}
```

Каждый подкласс должен иметь поле `description`, которое будет инициализироваться при создании объекта.
Правильно ли я реализовал логику? По идее в абстрактном классе поле должно быть объявлено с модификатором `private`, чтобы не нарушать инкапсуляцию.

UPD: Как вариант можно сделать такую реализацию, она выглядит более правильной, но меня почему-то смущает.

```
public abstract class SomeClass {
    private String description;
    public void setDescription(String description) { 
        this.description - description; 
    }
    public String getDescription() { return description; }
}


public class SubClass extends SomeClass {
    public SubClass() {
        setDescription("description");
    }
}
```

Comment: у тебя выходит что твой каждый подкласс не будет иметь поле description, измени на protected это тоже не нарушает инкапсуляцию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему не реализовать через конструктор в абстрактном классе, все наследники обязаны будут вызывать этот конструктор.

```
public abstract class SomeClass {
    private String description;
    public SomeClass(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getDescription() { return description; }
}


public class SubClass extends SomeClass {
    public SubClass(String description){
        super(description);
    }
}

public class SubClass2 extends SomeClass {
    public SubClass2(){
        super("значение по умолчанию для данного класса");
    }
}
```

Comment: Если, например, нужно в подклассе задавать какое-нибудь значение по умолчанию?

Comment: Можно создать конструктор без параметров который передает в родительский конструктор литеральную константу.

Answer (score 2):

Просто создаёшь поле в абстрактном классе с модификатором `protected`. Вообще странный вопрос, подумайте над тем что хотите получить в конечном счёте. На такие случаи есть отличные примеры из стандартной библиотеки. Например в классе `AbstractList` есть `protected` поле `modCount`, которое используется для отслеживания изменений над данными в производных классах, для того что бы в них корректно работали итераторы. Зачем далеко идти за примерами, стандартная библиотека полна отличных примеров.

Comment: Согласен с, Вами, но автор вопроса указал, что ему необходимо выполнение следующее условии "Каждый подкласс должен иметь поле description, которое будет инициализироваться при создании объекта."

Comment: @MikhailovValentine, да я видел и возможно не совсем конкретизировал свой ответ. Мне показалось, что этот вопрос, представляет из себя не столько конкретную задачу, сколько попытку разобраться в том, что из себя представляют абстрактные классы и как их применять. Думаю на таких качественных примерах как в стандартной библиотеке, это сделать проще всего. Могу ошибаться, но абстрактные классы нет смысла применять так как пытался их применить автор вопроса, разве что в каких то слишком уж "экзотических" случаях.